# "class X is public, should be in X.java" with Ideone online compiler

Tags: java, file, class, public

I am a student very new to programming and have made a simple program in java to convert units.

I am on a mac using **ideone compiler online**. I am receiving this error

```
Main.java:7: error: class AssessmentOne is public, should be declared in a file named AssessmentOne.java
public class AssessmentOne{
       ^
1 error
```

Here is my code (this is for an assignment I am working on hence the name):

```
package assessmentOne.pkg1;
import java.util.Scanner;

// MY NAME Assessment One


public class AssessmentOne{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { int choice;

    do

    { Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 = centimetre to inch, 2 = metres to feet, 3 = finish");
    choice = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

    if (choice == 1)

        {
        // converts centimetre to inch
        System.out.println("centimetre to inch");
            double centimetre;
            double inch;

            inch = 0;
            centimetre = Double.parseDouble(input.next());
            System.out.println("inch = centimetre * 0.3973");
        }

    else if (choice == 2)

        {
        // converts metre to feet
        System.out.println("metre to feet");
        double metre;
        double feet;

        feet = 0;
        metre = Double.parseDouble(input.next());
        System.out.println("feet = metre * 3.28");
        }

    else if (choice == 3)

        {
        // exits
        break;
        }

    } while (choice != 3);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Rename your file to `AssessmentOne.java`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the exact error message, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Finally I have put the fact that you are using Ideone online compiler in bold, because I think it's important in this case. Good luck!

Comment: Looks as if ideone insists your public class has to be called Main. See this answer here - you might want to look into using a proper full development environment, like Eclipse or IntelliJ stackoverflow.com/questions/22340309/

Answer (score 1):

As it says on a new Java project on that site:

```java
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
```

Either:

1. Remove the `public` part:

   ```java
   class AssessmentOne{
   ```
2. Rename the class to `Main`:

   ```java
   public class Main{
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove public in below line of code and it works straight away.

"public class AssessmentOne{"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "**public**" from  "**public class AssessmentOne{**". In other words, just write "**class AssessmentOne {**" and Voila! It would work.
I had the same problem and removing the "public" worked. Here is the link of a code that had the same problem. [Click to see](https://ideone.com/koe2Rz)

```
package assessmentOne.pkg1;
import java.util.Scanner;

// MY NAME Assessment One


class AssessmentOne{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  { int choice;

    do

    { Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("1 = centimetre to inch, 2 = metres to feet, 3 = finish");
      choice = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

      if (choice == 1)

      {
        // converts centimetre to inch
        System.out.println("centimetre to inch");
        double centimetre;
        double inch;

        inch = 0;
        centimetre = Double.parseDouble(input.next());
        System.out.println("inch = centimetre * 0.3973");
      }

      else if (choice == 2)

      {
        // converts metre to feet
        System.out.println("metre to feet");
        double metre;
        double feet;

        feet = 0;
        metre = Double.parseDouble(input.next());
        System.out.println("feet = metre * 3.28");
      }

      else if (choice == 3)

      {
        // exits
        break;
      }

    } while (choice != 3);

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but this error usually appears when the name of the java file is differente than the class name. When you declare your class as `public` the java file that contains it must have the same name than `.java`.

**Example**

```
public class Example {}
```

`Example.java`

Comment: I changed from

public class AssessmentOne {
to 
public class AssessmentOne.java {

and my error is

Compilation error time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
Main.java:5: error: '{' expected
public class AssessmentOne.java {
                          ^
1 error


Thanks for the reply

Comment: No, you must use `public class AssessmentOne {` and the file where you wrote it must be named `AssessmentOne.java`. The name of the file must be the same as the public class.

Comment: You can't change or see the filename on Ideone.com.